# Why does href appear not to work with id?

Tags: html, href, element

```
<a href="http://www.website.com"><h1><a id="Didn&#39;t-answer-your-question&#63;">Didn&#39;t answer your question?</a><!--ID end--></h1></a><!--link end-->
```

Can I have an id element inside a href element, for the link text or does this not work, if so do people have an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your markup.

You don't close the `<h1>` tag properly. Your `<a>` `id` may technically work, but I wouldn't recommend it as an element ID.

The one that's giving you an issue though is the fact that you have an `<a>` tag nested inside another `<a>` tag. That is not valid markup.

Your inner tag does not need to be an anchor tag, change it to a span or something and it should work fine.

```
<a href="http://www.website.com">
    <h1>
        <span id="Didn&#39;t-answer-your-question?&#63;">Didn&#39;t answer your question?</span>
        <!--ID end-->
    </h1>
</a>
<!--link end-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and to all who answered on here :)

Answer (score 0):

You didnt properly close the h1 tag but other than that it looks like it should work.

This is from the w3 website:
    I just returned from vacation! Here's a
    `<A id="anchor-two">photo of my family at the lake.</A>.`
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3